# Android App debugs via Eclipse with no error but Crashes from Play Store

Tags: android, debugging, exception, deployment

I'm having a real issue. I'm getting a crash every time I try and download my app through the play store, yet deploying via Eclipse it works perfectly fine.

I keep getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{vltrack.android/vltrack.android.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
```

Before that I was getting the same error but with vltrack.android.classes.VLTrack

I put these lines in the onCreate and getInstance methods and it removed that error, but do I have to do this for every piece of code I have in all the other activities etc??

```
private static VLTrack vlt;
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        vlt = this;
    }
    public static VLTrack getInstance(){
        return vlt;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this guide here and it functions correctly now

http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17